# I'm not sure why 'aus' is here or what this sentence means

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context

This is from 'Die Bremen Stadtmusikanten'.

> Jetzt weiß ich nicht, was aus mir werden soll.

What does 'aus' mean here?

Answer (score 6):

The phrase you need to look up and understand is "(etwas) aus etwas werden" and it very roughly translates to "sth/sb becomes of sth/sb" and the 'aus' has somewhat the same meaning as 'of' in this English expression. There are a few examples of this expression in [DWDS under (d)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/werden).

Jetzt weiß ich nicht, was aus mir werden soll --> Now I don't know what will become of me (thus depending on context it could for instance mean and also be translated with 'no clue what profession or job to take up in the future')